# Is it possible to disable HTTP on an azure app service, not just redirect it to HTTPS

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In azure app services you are able to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS either via the web.config file or through the custom domains blade in azure portal. Is it possible to disable HTTP completely without doing a redirect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve this:

- Go to Kudu console for the Web App
- Go into the `D:\home\site` folder
- Create a file called `applicationhost.xdt` in that folder, with the following content (you can drag/drop it from your local machine):

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
      <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <rule name="Disable HTTP" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="401" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>    
      </system.webServer>
    </location>
  </configuration>
  ```

This will make http requests fail with 401 (you can customize the response in the `<action>` tag).

Comment: Awesome. This is why I log into StackOverflow every day.

Comment: Would this also work for a linux based app service? It does not seem to work on my side.

Comment: @JoostPielage as of now the following checkbox works for me: Azure Portal > App Service > {some-web-app} > TLS/SSL settings > HTTPS Only

Comment: Cannot get it to work. Should this still work?

Comment: Nevermind, restart of app service was needed to pick up the change.